# How to make Logstash parse newly added/logged content to a file input in a real-time way

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

I am reading the [Processing Apache Logs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/1.5/config-examples.html#_processing_apache_logs) example in the Logstash Configuration Examples section of the Logstash Reference [1.5]. One of the sentences goes:

> "Any additional lines logged to this file will also be captured,
>   processed by Logstash as events, and stored in Elasticsearch."

I am trying to implement it by adding one more line to the log file being monitored while the Logstash shutdown has NOT completed. And that is basically what I meant by "real-time" in the question title.

## Below is how I actually tried it:

**Step 1. Pass in logstash-apache.conf to Logstash**

The version of the Logstash I'm using is 1.5.4. And the code for *logstash-apache.conf* is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/your/path/to/the/log/file"
    start_position => "beginning"
    type => "apache_access"
  }
}

filter {
  if [path] =~ "access" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }
  }
  date {
    match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  host => localhost
  protocol => "http"
  port => "9200"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The conf file is almost the same as the example. However, the type of "apache_access" is added to the file input plugin instead of being put in the mutate filter plugin, per reading the explanation on the site. Please replace the path within the file input plugin with yours.

For your convenience, the *sample log* is provided here:

```
71.141.244.242 - kurt [18/May/2011:01:48:10 -0700] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 566 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
134.39.72.245 - - [18/May/2011:12:40:18 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1189 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)"
98.83.179.51 - - [18/May/2011:19:35:08 -0700] "GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 1837 "http://www.safesand.com/information.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
```

After Logstash's processing, the standard out has 3 *results* in the rubydebug format, which can be seen in the uploaded image (of course, these 3 are also indexed in Elasticsearch):
[Image of 3 results appearing in the standard out in the rubydebug format after Logstash's processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TTI9.png)

***Please be noted that the pipeline generated by the conf file has not been shutdown at this point.***

**Step 2. Add one more line of log to the file using the text editor in the server and save the change**

This is the line I add, which should be the 4th line in the log file:

```
71.141.244.242 - kurt [18/May/2011:01:48:10 -0700] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 566 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3"
```

After doing this, I expected to have one more result showing in the standard out because I believe the file input plugin can be configured to do so as the file input plugin section in the same reference says:

> The plugin aims to track changing files and emit new content as it’s
>   appended to each file.

Unfortunately, nothing happened.

Am I on the wrong track, and doing the whole thing wrong? If not, could anyone here help me achieve what I intend to do, and possibly explain the mechanism behind it? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: logstash tracks the byte offset into the file.  If you've been editing the file by hand, it might be confused.  Shutdown logstash, remove the sincedb file, restart logstash (which should then reprocess the contents of the file) and then *concatinate* more lines onto the file (echo "foo" >> file).

Comment: @AlainCollins Thanks for the promptness. But echo "foo" >> file does not appear to be received by the shell, probably because the pipeline is not shutdown until you press CTRL-D or CTRL-C. And I think before you do that, pretty much every command does not get received by the shell. Even if the shell does, removing the sincedb file and restarting Logstash makes it reparse the whole file again that has already been processed before, which means the destination will have duplicates.

Comment: @AlainCollins And, to be honest, I don't quite understand the fact quite much that I have to press CTRL-C to complete the logstash shutdown if I use file {} plugin in the input section. When I specify stdin {} plugin in the input section, and use cat foo | ./logstash -f logstash-apache.conf to start the pipeline, I don't have to press either CTRL-C or CTRL-D to shutdown the pipeline.

Comment: Yes, you would have to do the echo in another shell window if your first window is busy running logstash.  I wasn't suggesting that 'echo' was a production-level way of adding data to your file; I assumed that some other process would take care of that (and that your manual editing of the file was also not production-level).

Comment: logstash is meant to run forever, monitoring the files or other inputs, doing the filtering, and sending the results to elasticsearch.  It's typically not run and then killed.

Comment: @AlainCollins Thanks a lot!!! Appending more data in another shell window works!